# mysql re-use auto increment id

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following situation,I simplified the table to keep things readable here.

**Table structure:** (note: `id` is `auto-increment`)

**columns :** `id,text,rid`

**Based on the input of a form, 2 rows are being inserted into a table.**

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id,text,rid) 
VALUES (NULL, $usertext1, ??),(NULL, $usertext2, ??)
```

Now, Where is my problem's at ?

I need the first ?? and the second ?? to be the same **int**, and Both need to be the **auto-increment** id from the first insert! I tried **LAST_INSERT_ID()** but it returned **0**.

The result how I'd like to have it :

1 | abctext | 1

2 | lalala  | 1

3 | fajoif  | 2

4 | oijgoi  | 2

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to do your inserts one at a time if you need a value from the previous one.

Comment: Why don't simply do an select higher id before insert ? I'm not sure to have understand your question

Comment: you cannot achieve the same integer at a time while using `auto-increment`

Comment: for the expected result you should use two tables and create a relation like  primary key with foreign key.
can you please provide the full php code of insertion?

Comment: @Noman, I'd make a cross relation table if I was allowed to do so. The table as-is is how I need to work with it. I can post some of the php code but it's not that interesting I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to follow something like this to get it done:

```
<?php 
$i=0;
$firstInsertId=0;
foreach($post as $value){// suppose each $post index contains the one complete post data
    $usertxt=$value['text'];
$sql="INSERT INTO tablename (id,text,rid) 
VALUES (NULL, $usertxt,$firstInsertId)";
$mysqli->query(sql);
if($i == 0)//flag to get first inserted Id
    $firstInsertId=$mysqli->insert_id;

  $i++;
}

$sql="update tablename set rid=$firstInsertId where id=$firstInsertId";
$mysqli->query(sql);
```